# Live vídeo streaming multiusuário

Tags: html, streaming

Tenho uma câmera, e gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

Inserir uma `frame`, `div`, ou o que for, para deixar essa câmera em tempo real (live) em uma página de um site. **Simplesmente irão dar play, e assistir o que está passando ao vivo**.

*Neste caso, tenho uma câmera IP, com uma porta já liberada para acesso externo*. Ex.: 111.222.333.444:8000.

Para que eu possa fazer isso, **preciso somente de um "player" para html** 
 que chame o meu IP ?

Ficará disponível para **multiusuários** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma bem simplista, você vai precisar rotear os requests em seu ip externo para o endereço local da câmera. Se ela fornece a entrega por http, já deve ter um servidor e player "nativo". Outro caminho é buscar uma solução de mercado, como o Windows Media Server ou o Wowza...

Mas ainda mais fácil é utilizar algum serviço que faça esse broadcast para você e disponibilize um player embedado (Youtube, Twitch, Mixer e etc)

Você terá que escolher o que atenda as suas necessidades e caiba no seu bolso.

Comment: Então Leandro, é uma intelbras HD, simples. Se eu colocar o IP direto, ela não abre um player. Só visualizo por rtsp (no VLC por ex.). Seria bem mais esquema eu colocar então no YouTube, assim eu gastaria só 1x banda para o envio, e o resto, iriam assistir direto do YouTube ?

Comment: Exato, aí você tem apenas um upload stream e a distribuição fica por conta da plataforma que você está usando, se fizer direto a disponibilidade vai depender da banda disponível que você tem em sua conexão.